# Laravel makes a redirection for no reason

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working on a Laravel app. I am currently working on the password reset feature. However, I am having an issue. I have two routes with the same name, /admin/password/reset. One takes the get, the other is used on post. No problem when I access the GET, but when I try the POST, I get redirected to the GET page without even having the action in my controller processed.

I tried everything I could I found such as adding a CSRF, still, it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
Route::prefix('admin/password')->middleware('guest')->group(function() {
    Route::get('email', function () {
        return view('admin.forgot');
    });
    Route::post('email', 'ForgotPasswordController@forgot');
    Route::post('reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@reset');
    Route::get('reset', function () {
        return view('admin.reset');
    })->name('admin.reset');
});
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    public function forgot(Request $request) {
        $credentials = request()->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);
        Password::sendResetLink($credentials);
        if($request->expectsJson()) {
            return success(__('messages.resetPasswordLinkSent'));
        }
        return view('admin.forgot')->with('sent', true);
    }

    public function reset(Request $request) {
        $json = $request->expectsJson();
        $credentials = request()->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'token' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|string|confirmed'
        ]);
        $errors = new \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag();

        $reset_password_status = Password::reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
            $user->password = Hash::make($password);
            $user->save();
        });

        dd('hello');

        if ($reset_password_status == Password::INVALID_TOKEN) {
            $errors->add('token', __('messages.invalidPasswordResetToken'));
            if ($json) {
                return error(__('messages.invalidPasswordResetToken'), 400);
            }
            // return view('admin.reset')->withErrors($errors);
        }



        if ($json) {
            return success(__('messages.passwordResetSuccess'));
        }
        // return view('admin.reset')->with('success', __('messages.passwordResetSuccess'));
    }

}
```

```
@extends('layouts.adminSplit')

@section('title')
    Réinitialiser le mot de passe
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="p-5">
    <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Réinitialiser le mot de passe</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="user" method="POST" action={{ url('admin/password/reset') }}>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @if(isset($success))
        <div class="alert alert-success mt-2" role="alert">
            {{ $success }}
        </div>
    @else
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="password" placeholder="Mot de passe">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Confirmation du mot de passe">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Réintialiser le mot de passe" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block"/>
    </form>
    @endif
    @foreach($errors as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" role="alert">
            {{ $error }}
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <hr>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I really don't get why it's happening and I have been stuck on this problem for the past half-hour...

Comment: Have you tried naming the POST route and hitting it via name?
Have you tried clearing the route cache (php artisan route:clear)?

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` and make sure you know your routes.

Comment: can you attach a route list screenshot? using php artisan route:list

Comment: @AhmedSaleh https://imgur.com/a/5dJxnKE

Comment: @RoboRobok https://imgur.com/a/5dJxnKE

Comment: @kiwibg yep, doesn't work

Comment: Try removing the validation of the request (or moving dd up).
It could be that the form validation is failing silently...

Comment: @kiwibg yes, it redirects when the validation fails... I tried using message bags, yet, it doesn’t work...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. The issue was that there was an auth middleware that was not allowing access to the function.

Try adding a constructor to your ForgotPasswordController:

```
public function __construct() {
   $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['forgot', 'reset']]);  
}
```

Comment: According to my route:list, no middleware on my route.